# Query problem how can i add or operator? with query dict

Tags: django

Hope You Are Good

My Problem is i want to find properties by cities and if we get none we want to find properties with location

but how can i achive this

i want to add or operator something to get that result

but the problem is how can i do that?

here is my following code (That doesn't work):

```
query = {}
if city:
    newCity = City.objects.filter(name=city.lower()).first()
    if newCity:
        query["city"] = newCity

    query["location__icontains"] = city.lower()
    
# if not query:
queryset = Property.objects.filter(**query).order_by('-id')
```

I want if properites with city doesn't found try with location!

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You can try like this using [`Q()`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/topics/db/queries/#complex-lookups-with-q-objects) object:

```
from django.db.models import Q

if city:
    queryset = Property.objects.filter(Q(location__icontains=city)|Q(city__name=city)).order_by('-id')
else:
    queryset = Property.objects.all()
```

Comment: what if someone dosen't provide city

Comment: add an if-else logic. Please see the updated answer.

Comment: but i have also more field

Comment: Then please update your question with more information and codes